# How do inline tailwind CSS and multiple file tailwind CSS differs?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, postcss

Do we have to write it inline like:

- index.css file which contains all tailwind starters

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

or in separate files like:

- index.css

  - file1.css
  - file2.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `index.css` file can contain utility classes.
You use a tailwind command `tailwind -i index.css -o output.css` to build and generate a css file.

In your html file: you need to use tailwind inline in `class` attribute:

```html
<body class="text-white border border-blue-400">

    you rest of body
</body>
```

One last this you need is tailwind configuration file, which is automatically created when you run `tailwind init` in your working directory. This configuration file looks something like this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['**/*.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

The purpose for this file is to check if any html file is using tailwind classes and if so based on that render `output.css` when you run build command.